# Angular Conditons best way

Tags: angular, string, typescript

Question for Angular best practies
I have a list of different objects. The questions are one of this list have a different value in the property like this

```
data =[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "operationStatusDescription":"pending"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "operationStatusDescription":"pay confirmed"
   }
]
```

in the view I have a table in agular, where with a for loop I display the data, I need to make a 'pay' button appear only on the column with pending status

in the if I used * `ngIf = "operationStatusDescription === 'pending'"` but I didn't want to use a condion with the string .. is there a better method?

thanks

A

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of where the code is used

Comment: Why don't you want to use a condition with the string? If your data is a string, then checking it sounds like the best way forward to me. Alternatives would be to use an enum or something like that, but if you're working with strings then I think it's fine for the condition to check the value of the string.

Comment: Then filter records in the component before binding.

Comment: Map your data structure into a view model with some property like “displayPayBtn” and use ngIf with that.

Comment: You could transform the data and add a boolean column that is used by the template. We often do that for fields/conditions that are for example calculated. So your object could look like `[{id: 1, operationStatusDescription: 'pending', isPending: true}, {id: 2, operationStatusDescription: 'not-pending', isPending: false}]`

Comment: The mapping could be done as following: `data.map(entry => ({...entry, isPending: entry.operationStatusDescription === 'pending'}))`